# Bootstrap - How to keep the natural container layout while fixing the container to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a Bootstrap one-page website, which uses a full-screen background. All content should be contained within the visible screen without having to scroll; i.e. I want to exactly position different elements with a fixed position.

I am currently stuck while trying to fix a container containing 3 equal columns. When I am fixing the container and position it 70px above the bottom, the columns move to left instead of keeping the natural centered position:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container front-page-widgets">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">

      <?php if ( dynamic_sidebar( 'front-left' ) ); ?>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <?php if ( dynamic_sidebar( 'front-center' ) ); ?>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <?php if ( dynamic_sidebar( 'front-right' ) ); ?>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.front-page-widgets {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 70px;
}
```

Would appreciate your advise how to keep the natural container layout while fixing the container to the bottom.

Comment: Consider building at least a sketchy jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely your `.container` moves to left because you set the `position: fixed` and it sticks to the very left site as designed.

If you want to center the Bootstrap's `.container` horizontally while `position: fixed` is applied you may need to add `left: 0` and `right: 0` to achieve that.

Works on all resolutions.

**[Bootply ex.](http://www.bootply.com/PJfHhQ5xMY)**